# Probability for dot product of two vectors of length n with k non zero elements to be non zero

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let two vectors `v1`, `v2` of length `n`.

Each vector has `k1` and `k2` non zero, positive elements.

The non zero elements' indices are uniformly selected over all possible combinations of indices (total n choose k options for each vector, each combination is equiprobable).

Both selections `k1` and `k2` are independent of each other.

[Note that the distribution of the non zero values themselves is unimportant]

Let `d = v1 dot v2`

What is the probability for d to be non zero? Meaning, what is the probability for at least one index of a non zero element in `v1` to be the same as a non zero element in `v2`?

I can't seem to wrap my head around this.

Comment: Are the elements of the vector in $\mathbb Z$?$\mathbb R$?$\mathbb C$?

Comment: You can't talk about probability without defining what is the distribution of the elements.

Comment: @Gulzar: Please edit the actual question into the question itself. The current formulation of the question makes no sense, and the question should be self-contained and not rely on the comments to be understood. (Comments are not always displayed if there are many of them.)

Comment: @joriki edited. There are k nonzeros, and n-k zeros. Either the indices overlap or not, causing the dot product to be non zero. Is it clearer now?

Comment: The elements are not in R. They are either positive or zero. I think that makes it clearer.

Comment: @Gulzar: The question still makes no sense. In a previous comment which you seem to have deleted now, you had written something about a uniform distribution. This is an essential part of the question. As TheHolyJoker pointed out above, it makes no sense to talk about probability without specifying a distribution. Generally speaking, if you have a question in written form that you want to ask here, please don't paraphrase it but provide the original question verbatim. Often, as in this case, a whole lot of effort is wasted to reconstruct the actual question from an incorrect paraphrasis.

Comment: The question was asked in a job interview i recently took, and I failed to answer. Perhaps I don't reconstruct the question well enough. However, I don't understand what doesn't make sense here. The dot product being nonzero relies only on the selection of inds of the non zeros, which has the same probability for every combination. Distribution of the non zeros is irrelevant. Assume they are all ones.

Comment: @Gulzar: That's a misunderstanding. The question wasn't about the distribution of the values of the non-zero elements but about the distribution of their positions. That every combination has the same probability is an essential piece of information that you had already provided in an earlier (now deleted) comment but which is still not provided in the question itself. The question is not well-defined without this information.

Comment: @joriki i will do it, i promise. please let me get home first

Comment: @joriki Edited. I hope this is much clearer now.

Comment: @Gulzar: Great, much clearer. It still doesn't state that the two combinations of indices are independent of each other (without this assumption the question can't be answered), but let's perhaps not be too exact about it :-) I've removed my critical comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First choose $k_1$ non-zero elements from $v_1$. Now choose $k_2$ elements one by one from $v_2$. When choosing the $r^\text{th}$ such element, there are $n-r+1$ elements to choose from, but $k_1$ of these will result in a non-zero dot product. So only $n-r-k_1+1$ of these elements contribute zero to the dot product. So the probability that a non-zero dot product is still possible is

$$\frac{n-r-k_1+1}{n-r+1}$$

Thus the probability that all $k_2$ choices contribute zero to the dot product is
$$\prod_{r=1}^{k_2}\frac{n-r-k_1+1}{n-r+1}$$

This equals
$$\frac{n-k_1}{n}\cdot\frac{n-k_1-1}{n-1}\cdots\frac{n-k_1-k_2+1}{n-k_2+1}$$

If $k_1+k_2>n$, this product is zero. Otherwise it is
$$\frac{(n-k_1)!(n-k_2)!}{n!(n-k_1-k_2)!}$$

This is the probability that the dot product is zero. You asked for the probability that the dot product is non-zero; I will leave this as an exercise :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_{jk}=|\{i\in[n]\mid\operatorname{sgn}v_{1i}=j\land\operatorname{sgn}v_{2i}=k\}|$, with $\operatorname{sgn}$ denoting the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function). Then

$$
a_{10}+a_{11}=k_1\;,\\
a_{01}+a_{11}=k_2\;,\\
\sum_{ij}a_{ij}=n\;.
$$

The dot product is zero exactly if $a_{11}=0$. Then $k_1=a_{10}$, $k_2=a_{01}$ and $a_{00}=n-k_1-k_2$. This is only possible if $k_1+k_2\le n$. In that case the number of admissible arrangements is given by the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients)

$$
\binom n{k_1,k_2,n-k_1-k_2}=\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!(n-k_1-k_2)!}\;.
$$

The total number of arrangements is

$$
\binom n{k_1}\binom n{k_2}=\frac{n!^2}{k_1!(n-k_1)!k_2!(n-k_2)!}\;.
$$

Thus the probability for the dot product to be zero is

$$
\frac{(n-k_1)!(n-k_2)!}{n!(n-k_1-k_2)!}\;,
$$

in agreement with TonyK’s answer.

Comment: Thanks :) makes sense for `k=2`, but what about larger k?

Comment: @Gulzar: Ah, sorry, I missed that the number of non-zero elements is specified. I'll edit the answer accordingly. The current version is not the answer for $k=2$ but for unspecified $k$, with every subset of indices of non-zero elements equiprobable.

Comment: @Gulzar: OK, I've edited the answer to address the actual question.

Comment: Thank you for your time!